# Как сделать триггер для суммирования значения в поле связанной таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Нужно что бы при вставке новой строчки или изменении поля Plan_Seller в таблице SELLERS, значение Plan_Seller суммировалось в поле Plan_Shop таблицы SHOPS, связанной по ID_Shop.

```
CREATE TABLE SELLERS(
    ID_Seller int primary key,
    Name_Seller char(80),
    Plan_Seller int,
    Total_Seller int,
    ID_Shop int
);
ALTER TABLE SELLERS ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_Shop) REFERENCES SHOPS (ID_Shop);

CREATE TABLE SHOPS(
    ID_Shop int primary key,
    Name_Shop char(80),
    Region_Shop char(80),
    Plan_Shop int
);

CREATE sequence sellers_auto_incr start with 1
increment by 1;
CREATE sequence shops_auto_incr start with 1
increment by 1;
```

Создал 3 варианта триггеров, но они выдают ошибки:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Plan_SellerTOShop_Seller
BEFORE INSERT ON SELLERS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO SHOPS(ID_SHOP, PLAN_SHOP) VALUES (:NEW.ID_SELLER, :OLD.PLAN_SELLER);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Plan_SellerTOShop_Seller
AFTER INSERT ON SELLERS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN   
    insert into SHOPS(PLAN_SHOP)
    select PLAN_SELLER from SELLERS;   
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Plan_SellerTOPlan_Shop_update
FOR INSERT ON SELLERS
compound TRIGGER
DECLARE 
     shop_sum SHOPS.PLAN_SHOP%TYPE;
     seller_inf SELLERS.PLAN_SELLER%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT SELLERS.PLAN_SELLER, SHOPS.PLAN_SHOP
    INTO seller_inf, shop_sum;
    IF seller_inf > 0 THEN
         shop_inf = seller_inf+shop_sum;
    END IF;
END;
```

Какой вариант самый верный и как его можно подредактировать для получения суммы?

Comment: Вы не могли бы вот это "столбик суммировал значение PLAIN_SELLER в поле SHOPS в столбик PLAIN_SHOP" более доходчиво пояснить? Это учебное задание ? Если нет, то зачем вам триггер?

Comment: 1) и 3) вообще не подходят, 2) не хвавтает значений и не понятно, что там суммируется

Comment: Если запись в shops с тем shop_id, который вы вставляете всегда есть, но для "суммирования" надо обновлять запись, а не вставлять новую. Т.е. вам нужен `update`, а не `insert`. Если же записи может не быть и ее возможно надо создавать, то следует использовать `merge`

Comment: @Mike а зачем запись добавлять или как её может не быть?

Comment: @0xdb Да, на фореджены не обратил внимания, написал для общего случая

Comment: @Mike Вчера не сразу понял - "фореджены", откуда происходит этот термин? Раньше не встречал, а гугл находит только ваши сообщения.

Comment: @0xdb Лень на английский переключаться, что бы написать "FOREIGN KEY", вот они в фореджены и превратились. А русское название "внешний ключ" как то не по душе :))

Answer (score 3):

Надо сделать так:

```
create or replace trigger Plan_Seller_To_Shop_Seller
after insert or update of Plan_Seller on SELLERS
for each row
begin
    update SHOPS set
        plan_shop = 
            coalesce (Plan_Shop, 0) + (:new.Plan_Seller - coalesce (:old.Plan_Seller, 0))
    where ID_Shop = :new.ID_Shop
    ;
end;
/
```

На заметку:

- Имена полей/переменных или `planSeller` или `plan_seller`, а у вас микс.
- Триггер при изменении `Plan_Seller` не нужен. Обычно все запросы связанные с этой операцией заворачиваются в функцию.
- В зависимости от бизнесс требований необходимо решить, может ли `Plan_Seller` принимать значение NULL. Если нет, нужно сделать поле NOT NULL в таблице.

Comment: Plan_Seller может быть NULL, судя по структуре ...

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, поправил, Хотя это надо в таблице поправить., продажи с неопределённым колличеством не имеют смысла, я думаю.

Comment: Благодарю, подскажите как написать триггер если значение plan_seller будет изменено, я уменьшил значение ячейки plan_seller, а значение plan_shop увелечено:
create or replace trigger PlanSellerTоShopSellerupdate
after update on SELLERS
for each row
begin   
    update SHOPS
    set plan_shop = coalesce (plan_shop, 0) + :new.Plan_Seller
    where ID_Shop = :old.ID_Shop;
end;

Comment: Я поправил ответ. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы внесли правку в вопрос дополнив условие на изменение plan_seller.

Comment: Благодарю. Внёс правку.

Comment: Благодарность на этом ресурсе принято выражать отметкой "принято" (галочка слева от ответа), если ответ полностью решил вашу проблему и/или голосованием плюс (стрелочка наверх), если вы находите ответ полезным.